# Why does Microsoft say Azure Functions is for small pieces of code?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Azure documentation says...

> Azure Functions is a solution for easily running small pieces of code,
>   or "functions," in the cloud.

Why is there the qualifier "small" in this text? Are there any numbers to elaborate on this claim?

Comment: There are limits on both memory and maximum run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there the qualifier "small" in this text?

I think they are trying to tell us that Azure Functions are not intended to take the place of large, long-running programs.  There are other Azure solutions better suited for running a high-resolution graphics renderer or a program to calculate Pi to some enormous number of places.  Azure functions are intended to fill a different niche where a trigger causes some code to run, calculate a result fairly quickly and then return that result and stop.

Which is not to say that Azure Functions couldn't (in theory) support longer running code but that's not what it is optimized for.

> Are there any numbers to elaborate on this claim?

The [Azure Functions scale and hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) page indicates that the default timeout for functions on the Consumption plan is five minutes and the maximum is ten minutes.  However the page also notes that http triggered functions must respond in 230 seconds or less no matter what the timeout value is.

Functions on the App Service plan can have an unlimited maximum timeout - presumably because we're paying whether we use it or not (but that's just a semi-educated guess).

Answer (score 1):

If we compare other services that Microsoft offers like Service Fabric, Functions, and App Services, Azure Functions are tiny. Service Fabric, and App Services have focused on deploying complete services. An Azure Function is really just a method call. As result a complete microservice may actually be made up of a collection of Azure Functions. An example of this is an API, each route for your API would actually be a completely independent Function. This may be an ideal world for you, or you may view this as too much effort.

[you can check out more here](https://medium.com/@WorkloadRancher/service-fabric-functions-and-app-services-which-ones-for-me-4e275128ed0)